2.4.5 - Duplicate Orders are observed for few Orders
We are facing issue with capturing payment for few orders as Transaction ID is missing for payflow credit card payment.
It is an intermittent issue and we observed this issue as few orders are processed but payment is not captured and without Transaction ID order created in Magento admin which ideally should not happen.
The customer does not reach to Success page, but in the background order is getting created with the missing transaction ID. So customer tries to submit payment again and here we get duplicate orders. i.e. same customer, same product but multiple orders in Magento admin(Some missing transaction id and one successful order with transaction id).
Steps to reproduce:
customer try to make payment with Credit card. in that case we get only "Declined" message and in background order was created with missing transaction id and status and states are blanked.
I have checked payment logs and it says that:

'result' => '12',
'pnref' => 'Something text',
'respmsg' => 'Declined: 15005-This transaction cannot be processed.',
'hostcode' => '15005',

I need to understand if payment declined then why order is created in Adobe admin?
debug logs says that -

report.CRITICAL: Placing an order with quote_id  is failed:
Declined [] []

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happened and how we can avoid this in the future please.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cshelp/article/why-did-i-get-api-error-codes-15005-15006-and-15007-ts1425
This is AVS error

Hi @rex For AVS  understand but I don't know why the order created is not getting cancelled.

can someone help me to resolve this issue?

We had a similar issue (order places, payment accepted but transaction ID missed) with one of our customers websites.
After doing the debugging we found that the issue was caused by a 3rd party module which triggered the error.  We had that extension to edit the orders on the admin section, which intercepted the order placing workflow misbehaving with the taxes selection which triggered this issue.
Having a way to trigger the error consistently can help to troubleshoot this faster. If you can trigger the error manually, try disabling the modules that might intercept the placing order workflow to see if that solves the issue.

Hi Serfe, I was tried to disable custom module but still we getting orders with missing transaction id.
In my case, if card is declined by Paypal payflow or any error occurred during the transaction(like customer have limit amount, Billing address is different etc..) at that time we are getting order with blank status and state and no transaction id.
